# How to link godaddy domain name to google compute engine?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, nameserver, godaddy

I have created compute engine in google cloud. After that I have create a zone with the record sets of `A` and `CNAME` using external ip of my compute engine instance.

I have got some name servers by default like, `ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.`.
But, it has `.` at the end of it and cloud services are not allowing me to take it off and adding it automatically even I remove it.

I tried to add that name servers in `godaddy` name servers. But I have an issue in godaddy domain settings. godaddy is not allowing me to add `.`(dot) at the end of name server. It throws error and not allowing me update name servers with the `.` dot ended.

I have been stuck here from Yesterday and I tried googling but didn't get satisfying result.

Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's likely to be just a UI thing with that provider. GoDaddy's made for the more general public and probably adds it automatically behind-the-scenes. Try it without the dot and see if `dig` shows the right records after.

Comment: I tried with out dots and waited until the name servers are updated. But it is not working.

Comment: Give us the domain so we can take a look.

Comment: @ceejayoz http://kausthubhya.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what expected. If you need godaddy to be your primary DNS server then just go to godaddy's
domain settings->additional settings->managed DNS page
In record section click on Add, then add A and C name records.
e.g. if your domain name is "example.com" and you want an entry for IP 114.64.78.9 as test.example.com then in A record say
Host as 'test' points to 114.64.78.9

Add CNAME record with
Host as 'test.example.com' points to '@'

Then wait for a few hours to get it to reflect globally or mention the godaddy's nameservers in your resolv.conf file

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confusing Name Servers with DNS entries.  Nameservers are what hold the A and CNAME records.  They are usually configured at a level above DNS Entries (A Records/CNAMES/MX/TXT, etc...).

If you are trying to point at the Google Cloud nameservers and have them host your Entries you need to edit the Primary nameservers at GoDaddy to point at Google Cloud.  Then you would create your A and CNAME records on Google's name servers.  If you want Godaddy to be your primary nameservers, then you need to load your A/CNAME records into Godaddy.  The `.` is a default added on to the end of all records, and is fine.

Here is a link to a post over at DigitalOcean that discusses the differences as well:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/name-servers-vs-a-record-ip

I hope this clears up the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Cloud DNS on GCP:

1. Make Compute Engine instance IP static
2. Create DNS zone (put your static IP address in IP field)
3. Create record set for A and CNAME

There is a video on YouTube https://youtu.be/lz72M0q2a6c